# python selenium ActionChains ALT+click

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I have set a selenium driver called "mydriver" in python. I need to ALT+Click on a link element I have located on a loop. The following code works fine for the first few elements but after a couple of links it goes to the link page (text) instead of downloading the associated text file:

```
ActionChains(mydriver).key_down(Keys.ALT).click(link).perform()
```

is these chain of actions incorrect?

Comment: The code looks correct. Could you add more details - ideally the complete code including the url to the page you are working with..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was related to holding ALT key and not releasing it, by adding the following code inside the loop the issue is resolved:

```
ActionChains(mydriver).key_up(Keys.ALT).perform()
```